# How to change the Icon when clicking on it in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, jsx

I`ve got 2 mui icons that I want to switch every click.
I mad a component for them and one of the props(called btnClicked) determines the state,
the component is rendered when clicking but the icon buttons does not change,
the code is :

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import {IconButton } from '@material-ui/core';
import AddIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Add';
import UndoIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Undo';
import CreateOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/CreateOutlined'
import BorderColorIcon from '@mui/icons-material/BorderColor'
const AddButton = ({onBtnClick,btnClicked,btnText,btnColor}) => {
    const create = () => {
        return (
            <div>
            <IconButton
            aria-label="add an alarm"
            onClick={onBtnClick}
            >
                <BorderColorIcon
                color="secondary"
                style={{cursor:'pointer'}}
                />
            </IconButton>
        </div>
        )
    }
    const undo = () => {
        return (
            <div>
            <IconButton
            aria-label="add an alarm"
            onClick={onBtnClick}
            >
                <UndoIcon
                color="secondary"
                style={{cursor:'pointer'}}
                />
            </IconButton>
        </div>
        )
    }
    console.log(btnColor)
    if ({btnClicked}) {
        return(
            <div>
                {
                    create()
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
    else
    {
        return(
            <div>
                {
                    undo()
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default AddButton
```

please help me :)

Comment: Can you check if you need curly brackets around btnClicked, in the line if ({btnClicked}) ?

Comment: Can you share a codesandbox of your all code! And use prettier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I've noticed is that you shouldn't need `btnClicked` inside of an object.

```
if (btnClicked) {
    return(
        <div>
            {
                create()
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your if statement contains unnecessary brackets. Instead of

```
if ({btnClicked}) {
```

you should have

```
if (btnClicked) {
```

If your component still doesn't update then you are not updating the props from the parent component. You need to make sure that `onBtnClick` triggers an update to the props